# Edit .sql file from container?

Tags: docker, github, terminal

sorry for maybe a noob question. I cloned a repo and spun up an image/container locally via docker.

When entering the container I can see the the file I want in the path after `root@5f8d2:/folder/fileiwant.sql` , but I cannot figure out to access that file to edit it and push back into github. Rather I can only see the file where I cloned it locally ie 'desktop/folder/fileiwant.sql' , but when I make edits to the file in the path from my github clone it does not reflect that in the file I navigate to within my container.

I tried `code .` to open from terminal when I am in my container but did not work.

Any thoughts

Comment: are you rebuilding your docker image after you edit the file? does your Dockerfile copy this into the container at build time?

Comment: well I am not even to edit the file because I cannot figure out how to locate/open it - does that help narrow down where I am stuck @ChrisDoyle

Comment: Can you share the repo. If you have edited the file you probably need ti rebuild the container

Comment: I have not edited the file , I really just cant figure out how to for instance I tried to use this post but xdg-open does not work  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212583/how-to-open-files-via-terminal

Comment: Can you share the link to the repo you cloned?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle you need to create a volume in docker, that solved it